# VsCode SVN show History

Tags: svn, visual-studio-code

How can I show a file's history in VsCode, for a project stored in svn ?

I installed the SVN plugin, but it does not seem to have this feature.

Thanks.

Comment: There're currently 11 extensions with the SVN keyword. Which one are you using? `johnstoncode.svn-scm` certainly has the feature.

Comment: I use johnstoncode.svn-scm. If I right click on a source file, there is no "SVN history" entry in the context menu

Comment: Is that meant to work? (I haven't really checked the documentation). I see file history in the "Subversion" side tab, "File History" pane.

Comment: Nice ! I didn't find it, I'm quite new to VsCode.
This is perfect for reading a file's history.
File history is not mentionned in the docs.

What about directory history ? (or multiple files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file, go to the Subversion panel and Drop down "File History".